# Optimization with non-negativity and norm constraint

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I am facing the following optimization problem:

$$\min_x w^tx \\
s.t. ||x|| = 1, \forall i: x_i \geq 0
$$

where $w$ and $x$ are real valued vectors. How would I solve this?

My background is not optimization (only some experience with equality constraints via Lagrange multipliers).

Comment: $w^t x$ is the inner product of $w$ and $x$?  What is the norm? $w^t x$ is a real number.

Comment: It should have been $x$ instead of $w^tx$.

Comment: Do you really mean ||w'*x||? Since w'*x is a scalar, the condition means that the objective w'*x is either 1 or -1. (oops sorry didn't see the clarification)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $\mathbf{w}\neq\mathbf{0}$. We have 
$$
<\mathbf{w},\mathbf{x}>=||\mathbf{w}||\, ||\mathbf{x}|| \cos(\varphi)=||\mathbf{w}|| \cos(\varphi),
$$
where $0\leq\varphi\leq\pi$ the angle between $\mathbf{w}$ and $\mathbf{x}$.

If $w_i\leq 0$ for all $i$ we obtain the minimal value in the only case $\varphi=\pi$ and $\mathbf{x}=\frac{\mathbf{w}}{||\mathbf{w}||}$.

If there are $i_0, j_0$ such that $w_{i_0}>0$ and $w_{j_0}<0$ then choose $\mathbf{y}$ such that $y_{i_0}:=0$ and $y_{j_0}:=-w_{j_0}$. Then $\mathbf{x}=\frac{\mathbf{y}}{||\mathbf{y}||}$.

If $w_i\geq 0$ for all $i$ then project $\mathbf{w}$ to the coordinate-axes. We obtain the vectors $\mathbf{w}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{w}_n$. The angles between $\mathbf{w}$ and $\mathbf{w}_i$ are $\varphi_i$. Choose $i_0$ such that the angle would be maximal (it is not necessarily unique). Then $\mathbf{x}=\frac{\mathbf{w}_{i_0}}{||\mathbf{w}_{i_0}||}$.

Comment: Take $w=(1,0)^T$, then the minimizing $x$ is $(0,1)^T$.

Comment: what about the non-negativiy constraint?

Comment: @leonbloy thanks. I modify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Construct $x$
from an **unconstrained** vector $u$
$$\eqalign{
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\s{\oslash}
\def\h{\odot}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\P{\frac{\o}{\pi}}
\def\PK{\frac{\o}{\|p_k\|}}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\e{{\large\varepsilon}}
\def\l{\lambda}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\LRB#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
p &= \tfrac12\, u\h u &\qiq &p\ge0,\quad\pi = \|p\| \\
U &= \operatorname{Diag}(u) &\qiq &dp = u\h du = U\,du \\
x &= \frac{p}{\|p\|} &\qiq &\|x\| = \frac{\|p\|}{\|p\|}=\o \\
&&\qiq &x\ge0 \\
\\
dx &= \LR{\frac{\pi^2\,I-pp^T}{\pi^3}}dp
  &\quad\;\;=&\P\LR{I-xx^T}U\,du \\
}$$
where $\h$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product.

Rewrite the objective and calculate the gradient wrt $u$
$$\eqalign{
\l &= w^Tx \\
d\l
 &= w^T\,\c{dx} \\
 &= w^T\,\c{\P\LR{I-xx^T}U\,du} \\
 &= \P\BR{U\LR{I-xx^T}w}^Tdu \\
 &= \P\BR{w\h u -(w^Tx)\,(x\h u)}^T du \\
\frac{\p \l}{\p u} &= \P\BR{w -(w^Tx)\,x}\h u \\
}$$
This gradient expression can be used in a gradient descent iteration
$$\eqalign{
p_k &= \tfrac12\,u_k\h u_k \\
x_k &= \frac{p_k}{\|p_k\|} \\
g_k &= \frac{u_k}{\|p_k\|}\h\BR{w -(w^Tx_k)\,x_k} \\
u_{k+1} &= u_k - \sigma_k\,g_k \\
k &= k+\o \\
}$$
where the recipe for the step length $\sigma_k$ differs from algorithm to algorithm.

A good starting point for the iteration is to find the minimum component of $w$ $$j=\arg\min_j(w)$$ and set $u=40\,\e_j\:$ (the corresponding cartesian basis vector).

This would be the **exact** solution to the related problem with $\|x\|=\|x\|_\o$

and will be closer to the solution of the current problem with $\|x\|=\|x\|_2\:$

than a random guess.